# Jquery Ajax, PHPMailer doesn't send emails even if there's no error but works if i use stand alone page with fix values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, localhost, phpmailer

I have this simple bootstrap form that i run on my localhost, it accepts `name` `email` and `message` and a custom `captcha` in a form of a math question; On submit i used jquery ajax to fetch the data to `emailme.php` that contains the phpmailer code.. My problem is, no email was sent even if there's no error and the network status is 200 and i can also see this:

```
http://localhost/emailme.php?name=myname&email=myemail@gmail.com&message=test
```

however it works if i just use the phpmailer stand alone code with fixed values. how can i make it work?

**HTML:**

```
<form id="emailme" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="e.g. John Doe">
        <span id="err_name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e.g. example@domain.com">
        <span id="err_email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        <span id="err_message" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="human">5 + 2 = ?</label>
        <input type="text" id="human" name="human" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Answer">
        <span id="err_human" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Send">
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#emailme").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var human = $("#human").val();
    var emailRegex = /(.+)@(.+)\.(com|edu|org|etc)$/g;

    if(name!==''&&email!==''&&message!==''&&human!==''){
        if(email.match(emailRegex)){
            if(human==7){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'emailme.php',
                    typ:'post',
                    data:{name:name,email:email,message:message},
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#mail-status").html(response);
                        $("#emailme")[0].reset();
                    },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
                        console.log(textStatus+errorThrown);    
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#mail-status").html("unable to submit form, you're not human");
            }
        }
        else{
            $("#err_email").append("Invalid email format");     
        }   

    }
    else if(name==''){
        $("#err_name").append("Name cannot be empty");
    }
    else if(email==''){
        $("#err_email").append("Email cannot be empty");
    }
    else if(message==''){
        $("#err_message").append("Message cannot be empty");
    }
    else if(human==''){
        $("#err_human").append("Please answer the security question");
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

   date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
   require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

   // Set the email address submissions will be sent to
   $email_address = 'myemail@gmail.com';

   // Set the subject line for email messages
   $subject = 'Test email from localhost using PHPMailer';

// Check for form submission
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])){

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->addAddress($email_address, 'myname');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = 'From:'.$_POST['name'].'(' . $_POST['email'] . ')'.'<p><b>Message</b><br/>' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: If there is no error message, you don't even go in your condition this mean that one (or more) of your values aren't set

Comment: Email function didn't work on localhost please test it on your server.

Comment: @HassanALi i'm using phpmailer, i said it works on stand alone page with fix values not coming from $_POST

Comment: You are working on localhost . there is no mail service available . So that's why its not gonna work .

Comment: @HassanALi i told you it works on my localhost if i paste the PHPMailer code on a stand alone page without form and ajax request and just use fix values.

Comment: @HassanALi, it's not submitting through localhost at all, it's submitting directly to gmail via SMTP.

Comment: Don't use the submitter's address as the From address - it's forgery and will be blocked by most ISPs. Put their address in reply-to, put yours in From. To debug your issue, `var_dump($_POST)` in your email script, make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: @Synchro how? i'm confuse.. first i need to setFrom into my own email and name then what about the addAddress and addReplyTo they're basically the same?

Comment: Yes, From and To addresses will be the same (both yours), but reply-to will be the submitter's. It's also a good idea to put the user's fields into the message body in case they are not quite valid, mistyped etc.

Comment: @Synchro i tried it here's my code changes:

$mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'myname');
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'myname');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

still no result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119007/discussion-between-twirlman-and-synchro).